# Array .push inside each loop returning array filling with same object

Tags: arrays, node.js, web-scraping

I'm trying to web scraping a page with cheeriosJS to get some information. The thing is that I need a each loop to overwrite a variable and push that variable to an empty array. Although I'm doing the web scraping correctly (each loop i get a different object), when i print the array once the loop has finished, i'm getting an array with the same object repeated multiple times.
What am i missing here?

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
const $ = require('cheerio');

let marketSpain = {
    country: 'Spain',
    name: 'IBEX 35',
    companies: []
}

let companySpain = {
    name: null,
    last: null,
    high: null,
    low: null,
    change: null,
    changePerCent: null,
    volume: null,
    time: null,
    purchase: false,
    sale: false
}

rp({
    uri: 'url',
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'Request-Promise'
    }
}).then(html => {
    $("table[class='genTbl closedTbl crossRatesTbl elpTbl elp30'] > tbody > tr", html).each((i, elem) => {
        companySpain.name = $("td[class='bold left noWrap elp plusIconTd'] > a", html).eq(i).html();
        companySpain.last = $("td", elem).eq(2).text();
        companySpain.high = $("td", elem).eq(3).text();
        companySpain.low = $("td", elem).eq(4).text();
        companySpain.change = $("td", elem).eq(5).text();
        companySpain.changePerCent = $("td", elem).eq(6).text();
        companySpain.volume = $("td", elem).eq(7).text();
        companySpain.time = $("td", elem).eq(8).text();

        marketSpain.companies.push(companySpain);
    });
    console.log(marketSpain)
    markets.push(marketSpain);


}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are modifying the same object and appending it to the end of the list. What you want to do is this:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
const $ = require('cheerio');

let marketSpain = {
    country: 'Spain',
    name: 'IBEX 35',
    companies: []
}

rp({
    uri: 'url',
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'Request-Promise'
    }
}).then(html => {
    $("table[class='genTbl closedTbl crossRatesTbl elpTbl elp30'] > tbody > tr", html).each((i, elem) => {
        marketSpain.companies.push({
            name: $("td[class='bold left noWrap elp plusIconTd'] > a", html).eq(i).html(),
            last: $("td", elem).eq(2).text(),
            high: $("td", elem).eq(3).text(),
            low: $("td", elem).eq(4).text(),
            change: $("td", elem).eq(5).text(),
            changePerCent: $("td", elem).eq(6).text(),
            volume: $("td", elem).eq(7).text(),
            time: $("td", elem).eq(8).text(),
            purchase: false,
            sale: false
        });
    });
    console.log(marketSpain)
    markets.push(marketSpain);


}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
})
```